# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')" when using vue-3d-model package

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to use the [vue-3d-model library](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but I'm running into this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')" before the page is even loaded.

I'm importing the library like so:

```
<script>
    import ModelStl from 'vue-3d-model';
    export default {
        components: { ModelStl }, ...
```

and these are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "jest": "^29.1.2",
    "jest-editor-support": "^30.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-3d-model": "^1.4.1"
```

From searching this error message, it seems like the problem is because Vue3 does not support Vue.extend (which seems to be the problem)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyEst.png)

Note that this is a javascipt file, however when I look at the github repo for the project, the equivalent file is in typescript, and the description says that it supports Vue 3.
https://github.com/hujiulong/vue-3d-model/blob/master/src/index.ts

What am I missing here?

I tried importing a package. I was expecting it to work out of the box. Perhaps I installed the wrong version or something?

Answer (score 0):

I also met the same problem. I upgraded the vue-3d-model version to 2.0.0 and the problem was fixed.

Comment: You can use the " npm install vue-3d-model@2.0.0-alpha.4 "